# Page still scrollable when menu is open

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I have my menu open, and I want to lock my regular webpage which is shifted to the side.

On "mm-opening" I am actually changing my body position to "static", and this does the trick for iPhone and certain Android devices!

However, on for example the Samsung Galaxy Note, while scrolling up and down on my mmenu, the regular webpage scrolls as well.

Any suggestions how to prevent this scrolling from happening?
Thank you.

Comment: Use overflow:hidden to stop the page from scrolling.

Comment: Thanks but where would I put that exactly?
I tried putting it in the body but it won't seem to do anything unless my body is also in a "fixed" position which I cannot do, because it automatically scrolls the page to the top when opening the menu (which is undesired)

Also, should I be applying this CSS change on "mm-opening" or "mm-opened"?

Edit: This seems to work on my local browser, but while testing it on an Android emulator, the page still scrolls - which leads me to think that something isn't working for Android.

Comment: Yeah, overflow: hidden doesn't seem to work at all on Android with frebsite's mmenu.

Does anyone else have a solution? Thanks.